# Building .NET Framework 4.8 project in Docker fails with "Reached end of stream before end of read"

Tags: c#, .net, docker, dockerfile

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8 AS build
WORKDIR /projectName
COPY . .
RUN nuget restore
COPY . .
WORKDIR /repoName/projectName
RUN msbuild ./projectName.csproj /p:Configuration=Debug
```

Locally, the msbuild step gives me no problems. Without a .dockerignore file, the build fails:

```
Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
```

When I add a .dockerignore file that looks like this...

```
./.git
./.idea
./.vs
./gen
./packages
./irrelevantProject1
./irrelevantProject2
# etc
```

...the build fails again, but with a different error message:

```
CompilerServer: server failed - server rejected the request 'Error reading response: Reached end of stream before end of read.' - b6c5574e-55ea-4d7d-adb3-e156ebd65296
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(71,5): error MSB6006: "csc.exe" exited with code -2146232797. [C:\repoName\projectName\projectName.csproj]
Done Building Project "C:\repoName\projectName\projectName.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"C:\repoName\projectName\projectName.csproj" (default target) (1) ->
(CoreCompile target) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(71,5): error MSB6006: "csc.exe" exited with code -2146232797. [C:\repoName\projectName\projectName.csproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:31.66
The command 'powershell -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; msbuild ./projectName.csproj /p:Configuration=Debug' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I've been stuck on this problem for days. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adding the bin/ and obj/ folders to your .dockerignore file? You'd want to prevent the locally built binaries being leaked into the container. That can mess things up.

Comment: Why are you doning a full copy twice? normaly in the first step you just copy the csproj file for the nuget restore

Comment: Notice Docker image "4.8" has been upgraded recently - and I compared two compilations (old succeeds, recent fails) when Build Engine version has changed from 16.9.0+57a23d249  to 16.11.0+0538acc04

Comment: Any chance this is something silly with file encoding (UTF-8 vs. Unicode, or maybe some extra BOM at the beginning) or line breaks (LF vs CRLF, etc.)?

Comment: @Schwarzie2478 I get the same results whether I copy just the .csproj files or do a full copy.

Comment: I sometimes get a different error: `CompilerServer: server failed - server rejected the request 'Exception during compilation: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.' `.

Comment: Could this be just an issue of different workdir specifications?

Answer (score 2):

Allocating more memory to the build solved this problem.

```sh
docker build -t projectName -m 4g .
```

Answer (score 1):

A collegue of mine points me this compiler bug https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/59336

According to comments, compiler crashes on anonymous delegate function declaration and also when preview features are used (like "!!" syntax) but then removed from recent compiler version.

Fix is not yet available in recent Docker SDK .Net 4.8 image